# How do you typically pay a deposit for a house?

Tags: united-kingdom, household

I am in the final stages of buying a house. My solicitor has given me bank details and requested that I send the full amount owed for the house + solicitors fees - mortgage. This totals around 120,000 so no small amount of money.

My solicitor seems to think that a direct transfer will be fine. I will go into the bank to do this and request the money be moved personally.

Does this sound acceptable, what concerns me is:

A: The solicitor could have given me anyone's bank details, is this the usual way to transfer the sum needed to cover the house minus the mortgage? (I currently have no reason to distrust them, they seem legitimate)

B: My solicitor has not told me an exchange or completion date, it seems odd to request the money before i have even exchanged contracts.

C: My solicitor wants the full amount now instead of the smaller deposit (10%?) used to tie me in to the contract once exchanged.

This is a UK property

Comment: B - No you would be provided with dates, before you transfer money. C - Again fishy. The bank will not release the mortgage more than a day before the completion date. I will be quite wary about your solicitor. Are they registered with any of the law body.

Comment: @DumbCoder: The solicitor holds the funds. It's not unusual at all. The smaller deposit is paid much earlier during proceedings.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - No the smaller deposit need not be paid so early without even the dates being confirmed. When I bought mine, I believe I paid in around 2-3 weeks earlier(completion date) and I knew my dates. I checked with 2 of my friends also who bought their houses. I am not saying the solicitor is fishy, for sure, but he might be trying to earn some interest on the deposit. And the bank will in no way going to transfer the mortgage funds so early.

Comment: But if the solicitor does ask the bank to release the mortgage amount without even the dates been clarified, I will be very wary.  http://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/showthread.php?t=2131395

Comment: Update: The solicitor informed me that she intended to exchange and complete on the date that I would have transferred the money though she said if I preferred I could pay the smaller deposit on exchange and wait a few days for the full completion.

Comment: I would send a large sum of money like this via CHAPS, as you can specify the recipient's details and these will be checked manually by workers at the banks. Solicitors normally ask for CHAPS only payments, although they might accept Faster Payments these days(?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A. Bank transfer is the normal way to do it. The Law Society will (eventually) make good any losses incurred on money held by solicitors acting fraudulently, so your money should not be at risk, provided you make sure to transfer the money to the account number your solicitor gave you.

B. It's not just normal but essential to transfer the money before exchanging contracts, since the deposit has to be paid by your solicitor to the vendor's solicitor as part of the  exchange process. You can't wait to pay the deposit until after you've exchanged, because you haven't exchanged until you've paid the deposit.

C. If you really want to put down the 10% deposit now and pay the rest upon completion, that should be possible -- talk to your solicitor about it.

Comment: A isn't entirely true. I don't think the 'Law Society` will reimburse in case of the solicitor running away with your money. I have read cases of fraud solicitors running away with client's money.

Comment: @DumbCoder Here's a link to the details of the Solicitors' Compensation Fund: http://www.sra.org.uk/solicitors/handbook/compfund/content.page

Comment: Wow you have it rough in the U.K.  Here in the U.S. you pay a minimal earnest money deposit (I've paid in the range of $500 to $1000) and nothing else gets paid until the day of closing using a wire transfer - at least in all the deals I've ever been a part of.

Comment: @Michael: Nothing else gets paid to the seller, no, but the money is often held in escrow from a few days beforehand. Which makes sense.

Comment: @Michael - Nope it isn't rough but quite drawn out and it takes time. Only bad thing is being gazumped just before finishing the sale.

Comment: @DumbCoder I've never heard of anybody in the U.S. doing an oral offer, it always seems to have to be in writing - perhaps to prevent just this phenomena.

Comment: @Michael Different system. Making an offer in the US is equivalent to exchange of contracts in the UK -- it's the point at which the deal becomes binding on both parties. Offers in the UK can be extremely informal because they don't bind anyone to anything.

Comment: @MikeScott : "Making an offer" is binding?!? What if the offer isn't acceptable to the seller? Is the seller still bound?  Seems odd.